# How do position Search box on top of this datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am trying to position the searchbox outside the datatables on top of my page.

I have created an input search text-box on top but I am not sure how to append the datatables search into my search textbox.

Here is what I have. Please see link to code below. Thanks.

https://live.datatables.net/fofimale/51/edit

```js
var filtered = [];

$(document).ready( function () {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    
paging: false,
scrollX: true,
scrollCollapse: true,
lengthChange: false,
searching: true,
ordering: false,
fixedColumns:   {
            left: 1
},
    

initComplete: function () {
   $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function( settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter ) {
            // Don't display rows if nothing is checked
            if (filtered.length === 0) {
                return true;
            } else if (filtered.includes(searchData[1])) {
                 return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
      );
    }
  });
  
  $('.filter').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    var index = filtered.indexOf( val );
    
    if (checked && index === -1) {
      filtered.push(val);
    } else if (!checked && index > -1) {
      filtered.splice(index, 2);
    }
    //console.log(filtered);
    table.draw();
  });
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="myInputTextField">
    <div class="container">
    
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="Technical Author" unchecked />Technical Author</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="Software Engineer" unchecked />Software Engineer</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="System Architect" unchecked />System Architect</label>

      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$4,525</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2012/08/06</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>2010/10/14</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>2009/09/15</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2012/12/18</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>2010/03/17</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michael Silva</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2012/11/27</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Paul Byrd</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2010/06/09</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gloria Little</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2009/04/10</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2012/10/13</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Dai Rios</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>2012/09/26</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2011/09/03</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>2009/06/25</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2011/12/12</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2010/09/20</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2009/10/09</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>2010/12/22</td>
            <td>$4,525</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2010/11/14</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>2011/06/07</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ebony Grimes</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>2010/03/11</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Russell Chavez</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>2011/08/14</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michelle House</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2011/06/02</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Suki Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>2009/10/22</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/05/07</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2008/10/26</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Martena Mccray</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/03/09</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Unity Butler</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/12/09</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/12/16</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2010/02/12</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2008/12/11</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>2008/09/26</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Miriam Weiss</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2011/02/03</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bruno Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>2011/05/03</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Odessa Jackson</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2009/08/19</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Thor Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2013/08/11</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Finn Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/07/07</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Elton Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cara Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Lael Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Shad Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Related: [Datatables - Search Box outside datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5990386/12567365). The techniques/answer may be a bit old, but should still work - although you may want to [update the option names](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert) (e.g. `dom` instead of `sDom`).

Comment: Thankyou. I tried to apply it to my table and it did not work. Probably because the technique is old?

Comment: What does "it did not work" mean, specifically, in this context? There are 12 different answers - and none of them helped?

Comment: What about [Search Box datatable outside the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72825295/search-box-datatable-outside-the-table)? And probably others. I think this question has been asked (and answered) a few times.

Comment: As andrew has eluded to, just add a textbox where ever you'd like on your page and then when the value changes just call `[dataTable].search([value]).draw()` the `draw` bit is important because that's what triggers the table to redraw with the filtered data.

Comment: Please see my updated example based upon the above links . You can see the search textbox on top is not working - https://live.datatables.net/fofimale/53/edit. Not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Couple of small issues in your linked example. The scope of the `table` variable. You defined that variable inside the `$(document).ready( function () {` function so it's not accessible inside of the `$('#myInputTextField').keyup(function() {` function. Also inside that function you are referencing a `example` variable and not the `table` variable. Make those small changes and it all works. If you want I can post an answer with the changes as a working example.

Comment: Thankyou, if you can post working example, it will be great. I am new to Javascript and not able to figure out how to include the keyup inside .ready function.

Comment: Ok, give me a few minutes to write it up and document the changes i made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on our discussion in the comments here is a working example with the small changes to your example.

```js
var filtered = [];
/* 
  I moved the declaration of this variable to here so it
  can be accessed in the change event of the filter
*/
let table;

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Just assign to the global table variable
  // Nothing else is changed in here
  table = $('#example').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    searching: true,
    ordering: false,
    fixedColumns: {
      left: 1
    },
    initComplete: function() {
      $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function(settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter) {
          // Don't display rows if nothing is checked
          if (filtered.length === 0) {
            return true;
          } else if (filtered.includes(searchData[1])) {
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        }
      );
    }
  });
  /* Nothing in here was changed */
  $('.filter').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    var index = filtered.indexOf(val);

    if (checked && index === -1) {
      filtered.push(val);
    } else if (!checked && index > -1) {
      filtered.splice(index, 2);
    }
    table.draw();
  });
});

/*
  Inside this function you were using an undefined variable `example`
  I simply changed this to use the now globaly defined table variable
*/
$('#myInputTextField').keyup(function() {
  table.search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="myInputTextField">
<div class="container">

  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="Technical Author" unchecked />Technical Author</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="Software Engineer" unchecked />Software Engineer</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="System Architect" unchecked />System Architect</label>

  <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$3,120</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$4,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$3,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$4,525</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>$4,080</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>$6,730</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td>$5,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>$3,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>$5,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td>$4,200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>2008/10/16</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2012/12/18</td>
        <td>$4,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>2010/03/17</td>
        <td>$2,875</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael Silva</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2012/11/27</td>
        <td>$3,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Paul Byrd</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2010/06/09</td>
        <td>$5,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gloria Little</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2009/04/10</td>
        <td>$3,120</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bradley Greer</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2012/10/13</td>
        <td>$3,120</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dai Rios</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>2012/09/26</td>
        <td>$4,200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2011/09/03</td>
        <td>$4,965</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yuri Berry</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>2009/06/25</td>
        <td>$3,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Caesar Vance</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2011/12/12</td>
        <td>$4,965</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Doris Wilder</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2010/09/20</td>
        <td>$4,965</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>2009/10/09</td>
        <td>$2,875</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>2010/12/22</td>
        <td>$4,525</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2010/11/14</td>
        <td>$4,080</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>2011/06/07</td>
        <td>$3,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ebony Grimes</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>2010/03/11</td>
        <td>$2,875</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Russell Chavez</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>2011/08/14</td>
        <td>$3,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michelle House</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2011/06/02</td>
        <td>$3,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Suki Burks</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>53</td>
        <td>2009/10/22</td>
        <td>$2,875</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/05/07</td>
        <td>$6,730</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2008/10/26</td>
        <td>$6,730</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Martena Mccray</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/03/09</td>
        <td>$4,080</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Unity Butler</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/12/09</td>
        <td>$3,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/12/16</td>
        <td>$4,080</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2010/02/12</td>
        <td>$4,200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>62</td>
        <td>2009/02/14</td>
        <td>$4,965</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2008/12/11</td>
        <td>$4,200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>2008/09/26</td>
        <td>$5,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Miriam Weiss</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2011/02/03</td>
        <td>$4,965</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bruno Nash</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>2011/05/03</td>
        <td>$4,200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Odessa Jackson</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2009/08/19</td>
        <td>$3,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thor Walton</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2013/08/11</td>
        <td>$3,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Finn Camacho</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/07/07</td>
        <td>$4,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Elton Baldwin</td>
        <td>Data Coordinator</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2012/04/09</td>
        <td>$6,730</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2010/01/04</td>
        <td>$4,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>2012/06/01</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2013/02/01</td>
        <td>$2,875</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cara Stevens</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/12/06</td>
        <td>$4,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hermione Butler</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2011/03/21</td>
        <td>$4,080</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lael Greer</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2009/02/27</td>
        <td>$3,120</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2010/07/14</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shad Decker</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/11/13</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael Bruce</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>2011/06/27</td>
        <td>$4,080</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Donna Snider</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/01/25</td>
        <td>$3,120</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: And as a refinement, if the asker wants to hide the default global search field, they can use something like `dom: 'lrtip'` ([documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)). Note the `f` (filtering input box) is excluded from `lrtip`, to do this.